# Numeric promotions in C#

Tags: c#, integer-promotion

In C#, why can't we add `int` to `long`? Why does the compiler need implicit conversion from `int` to `long` to perform the operations?

Similar for `byte` to `short` or `short` to `int`: why is an implicit conversion required?

Can someone clearly explain the purpose of numeric promotions and binary promotions in C#

Comment: `Why can't in C# can we...` so can't or can?

Comment: Short answer: because it is how it was deisgned. A bit longer, but certainly not complete: it was designed simlar to other languages. The representation in memory is not the same. There is a lot of "implicit" things needed to prepare both numbers to be added by the basic operations of the CPU. (how negative numbers are represented - or not, what happens if it overflows the maximum size in memory, etc...)

Comment: maybe I mis-edited it. I thought/assumed maybe the OP confused implicit with explicit, since you don't need to do an implicit conversion yourself, so...

Comment: Imagine if an `int` was added to a `long` *without* implicit promotion, I don't know what that would mean. In other cases (such as adding byte to byte) there is a clear alternative, but here I don't see it.

Comment: @Pac0 original post was difficult to read, so I just reverted explicit to implicit.

Comment: Why not ? it's worked.

Comment: _"Why does the compiler need implicit conversion from int to long to perform the operations"_ - because the closer you get to the metal, the less "implicit conversions" / mixed-type operations there are? On the CPU there may even be two different Hardware-Adders for each bit-width ... and if ASM just has Add(int, int) or Add(long, long) you also _must_ do one of them ...

Comment: @Fildor or more... think of packed/SIMD arithmetic instructions like. But including that that will make the answer a bit complex.

Comment: @JHBonarius I am aware I "dumbed it down". Last time I dove down that deep was at University ... so I admit I phrased it as good as I felt comfortable, still :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the underlying CIL `Add` instruction that the C# compiler must use for adding integral values requires that both values are the same size.

Therefore in order to use the `Add` instruction to add two integral values of differing sizes, the C# compiler must emit CIL instructions to extend the smaller of the two values to be the same size as the larger.

An obvious follow-up question would be "But why doesn't CIL include instructions to add integral values of different sizes?". We can't answer that question - only the designers of CIL can answer why.

We can only guess: Maybe because it was not necessary to complicate the CIL instruction set and thus its implementation - and many processors lack an `Add` instruction to add integral values of differing sizes so adding that to the CIL instruction set would provide no benefit.

However do note that the JIT compiler for a processor with an `Add` instruction that worked with operands of different sizes could in theory detect such cases and emit the more efficient instructions, without any need for direct support in the CIL instruction set.